# Как прослушивать используемый com-port?

Tags: c#, com-port

Есть десктопная программа, которая отправляет команды устройству, подключенному  через com-port. Есть ли в с# возможность сниффить траффик от софта к устройсктву? 
В голову приходит что-то вроде Mitm, т.е. создать свой порт и пропускать траффик через него. Такое возможно? Или нужно делать как-то иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну раз ответов нету. Опишу то что нашел. 
Есть софт Virtual Serial Port Emulator(Гуглится). Для x32 - бесплатно. 
Позволяет создавать виртуальные порты, к которым можно подключаться 2+ приложения одновременно. 
В нем создаем устройство типа Connector. Этот тип создает один виртуальный порт, к которому можно подключаться несколько раз. 
Цепляем к нему софт, который хотим слушать. И наш софт, который будет слушать. 
При получении данных от прослушиваемого софта, пересылаем данные на порт устройства. Аналогично поступаем с ответом устройства.

Таким образом получаем Mitm Com port. Soft <-> Sniffer <-> Device